# python3 pandas: how to fast find the latest number of months that have value is not 0

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

There is Dataframe as following:

```
id  year month y sinx
 1  2019  1    0   1
 1  2019  2    0   2
 1  2019  3    1   3
 1  2019  4    0   4 
 1  2019  5    0   5
 1  2019  6    0   6
 1  2019  7    0   7
 1  2019  8    2   8
 1  2019  9    0   9
 1  2019  10   0   10
 1  2019  11   0   11
 1  2019  12   0   11
 1  2020  1    0   12
 1  2020  2    0   13
 1  2020  3    2   14
 1  2020  4    0   15 
 2  2019  1    0   1
 2  2019  2    0   2
 2  2019  3    0   3
 2  2019  4    0   4 
 .......
```

I want to get the the number of months that each id before each month that the value (y column) is not 0, if there is no previous month or there is no previous month that the values is not 0, just set the value is -1.

for example as the above Dataframe, I want to get the following result.
Moreover the Dataframe is about 5M is large. the speed should be fast:

```
 id  year month y sinx  num_month
 1  2019  1    0   1      -1
 1  2019  2    0   2      -1
 1  2019  3    1   3      -1
 1  2019  4    0   4       1
 1  2019  5    0   5       2
 1  2019  6    0   6       3
 1  2019  7    0   7       4
 1  2019  8    2   8       5
 1  2019  9    0   9       1
 1  2019  10   0   10      2
 1  2019  11   0   11      3
 1  2019  12   0   11      4
 1  2020  1    0   12      5
 1  2020  2    0   13      6
 1  2020  3    2   14      7
 1  2020  4    0   15      1 
 2  2019  1    0   1       -1
 2  2019  2    0   2       -1
 2  2019  3    1   3       -1
 2  2019  4    0   4       1 
 .......
```

Comment: Why is there a  `1` in the second to last row of the `y` column?

Comment: thanks for your comment. you mean the last row? since the last row 2019 4  the latest month that the y value is not 0 is 2019 3, the num_month is 1

Comment: Look at the `y` column difference between input and output in the second-to-last row.  am going to assume that `y` colun in your output is correct and that you made a mistake with the input data.

Answer (score 3):

Getting the cumulative count is alright, but the logic to get the `-1` values was a little bit tricky. These are all vectorized pandas methods, so it should be performant on millions of rows:

1. You can `groupby` the necessary columns as well as the the `cumsum` of `y` in preparation for getting the `cumcount()`
2. However, you want to do the `cumcount` for one further row, so I fix the last row of each group with `np.where()`
3. The slightly trickier part is then changing the values to `-1`. I use similar techniques as the previous steps to achieve it, ultimately using `mask` to change the relevant values to `-1`, based off some conditions.

---

```
m = df.groupby(['id', 'y', df['y'].cumsum()]).cumcount() + 1                 ########## setup you base getting cumcount
df['num_month'] = np.where((m == 1) & (m.shift() > 1), m.shift() + 1, m).astype(int)  # extend cumcount one further row per group for first line of code
s1 = df.groupby('id').transform('idxmin').iloc[:,0]                      ############## get index location of first value per group and return as series with same length
s2 = df.groupby(['id', (df['y'] > 0).cumsum()]).transform('idxmin').iloc[:,0] ######### get index location of first non-zero value per group and return as series with same length
df['num_month'] = df['num_month'].mask((s1 == s2) | (s1 == s2.shift()), -1) ########### using s1 and s2 conditions, update the necessary rows to -1
df
Out[1]: 
    id  year  month  y  sinx  num_month
0    1  2019      1  0     1         -1
1    1  2019      2  0     2         -1
2    1  2019      3  1     3         -1
3    1  2019      4  0     4          1
4    1  2019      5  0     5          2
5    1  2019      6  0     6          3
6    1  2019      7  0     7          4
7    1  2019      8  2     8          5
8    1  2019      9  0     9          1
9    1  2019     10  0    10          2
10   1  2019     11  0    11          3
11   1  2019     12  0    11          4
12   1  2020      1  0    12          5
13   1  2020      2  0    13          6
14   1  2020      3  2    14          7
15   1  2020      4  0    15          1
16   2  2019      1  0     1         -1
17   2  2019      2  0     2         -1
18   2  2019      3  1     3         -1
19   2  2019      4  0     4          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `groupby` with `ffill`

```
s = df.month.mask(df.y.eq(0)).groupby(df.year).apply(lambda x : x.ffill().shift())
df['New'] = (df.month-s).fillna(-1)
df
Out[35]: 
    id  year  month  y  sinx  New
0    1  2019      1  0     1 -1.0
1    1  2019      2  0     2 -1.0
2    1  2019      3  1     3 -1.0
3    1  2019      4  0     4  1.0
4    1  2019      5  0     5  2.0
5    1  2019      6  0     6  3.0
6    1  2019      7  0     7  4.0
7    1  2019      8  2     8  5.0
8    1  2019      9  0     9  1.0
9    1  2019     10  0    10  2.0
10   1  2019     11  0    11  3.0
11   1  2019     12  0    11  4.0
12   1  2020      1  0    12 -1.0
13   1  2020      2  0    13 -1.0
14   1  2020      3  2    14 -1.0
15   1  2020      4  0    15  1.0
16   2  2019      1  0     1 -7.0
17   2  2019      2  0     2 -6.0
18   2  2019      3  0     3 -5.0
19   2  2019      4  0     4 -4.0
```